# ¿Cómo obtener por separado los valores de un array en php?

Tags: php

Tengo un array que lo muestro con:

```
print_r($Dni->get('67828282', true));
```

y me sale asi

> ```
> Array ( 
>           [dni] => 67828282 
>           [nombres] => elmer 
>           [apellido_paterno] => carillo 
>           [apellido_materno] => pando 
>         )
> ```

Quisiera obtener cada resultado por separado.

Hago un `var_dump` pero me salen otras cosas.

Espero su ayuda gracias.

Comment: Separados como? cada valor en una variable? o dentro del mismo array, puedes mostrar un ejemplo?. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

si es un array podras obtener cada dato con un foreach asignandolos a una variable, mas o menos asi;

```
     foreach($Dni as $index => $value){
    $dni        = $value['dni'];
    $nombres    = $value['nombres'];
    $apePaterno = $value['apellido_paterno'];
    $apeMaterno = $value['apellido_materno'];
}
```

o de esta otra forma tambien resulta:

```
$dni        = $Dni['dni'];
$nombres    = $Dni['nombres'];
$apePaterno = $Dni['apellido_paterno'];
$apeMaterno = $Dni['apellido_materno'];
```

Answer (score 1):

En PHP cuando tienes un ***array asociativo***, como es tu caso puedes ***obtener un array con las claves*** (keys) con el método **array_keys()** y ***obtener un array con los valores*** con el método **array_values()**.

Ejemplo:

```
$arr_origen = [...];

$arr_of_keys   = array_keys($arr_origen);
$arr_of_values = array_keys($arr_origen);
```

Puedes visitar la documentación de estos métodos en: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php y 
http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leerlo recorriendo el array con [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php):

#### Si quieres leer sólo el valor:

```
$arr=$Dni->get('67828282', true);

foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    echo $row["dni"]."<br />";
    echo $row["nombres"]."<br />";
    echo $row["apellido_paterno"]."<br />";
    echo $row["apellido_materno"]."<br />";
}
```

#### Si quieres imprimir la clave y el valor

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k.": ".$v."<br />";
}
```

Esta segunda posibilidad te imprimirá algo así:

```
nombres: elmer 
apellido_paterno: carillo 
apellido_materno: pando
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrer el array y sacar cada valor por separado.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'indice es '.$key.' y el valor es '.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp=$Dni->get('67828282', true);
```

`$temp[0]` para la primera pos del array y asi con cada uno

Comment: Hola Gamboa, puedes explicar mejor la respuesta? Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignar a variables el contenido de tu array con la función [list($var1 [,$...])](http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php).

```
$datos = [ 
  "dni" => 67828282, "nombres" => "elmer" 
  "apellido_paterno" => "carillo" 
  "apellido_materno" => "pando"
];
list($dni, $nombres, $apellidoPaterno, $apellidoMaterno) = $datos;
```

Comment: Usar `list` podria plantear un problema en caso de que el array no siempre tenga esos datos. Si te faltara por ej $apellidoPaterno, list devolveria $apellidoMaterno como $apellidoPaterno y en $apellidoMaterno devolveria null. Quiero decir, list te OBLIGA a que todos los parametros esten definidos en el array.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la función extract de PHP. Así obtendrás cada llave como una variable. [Extract PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php)

```
    $losdatos['varx'] = "Value";
    extract($losdatos,  EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, null);
    echo $varx; // "Value"
```